# find & return the longest word in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can someone please let me know what is going wrong here? Whenever I type in this as a test case (console.log(longestWord("what the hell is going on")) and I get 'what' back as the longest word...it works on pretty much every other case I tested ...its driving me crazy please help. thank you!!!

```
function longestWord(string) {
var words = string.split(' ');

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = words[i];

    var longestWord = words[0];

    if (longestWord.length < currentWord.length) {
         longestWord = currentWord;
    }
}
return longestWord;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were resetting your longest word with every iteration of the loop. Set initial (first) longest word before the loop runs and then it will work properly.

```js
function longestWord(string) {
  var words = string.split(' ');
  
  // Set the intial longest word out here 
  var longestWord = words[0];
  // Need to loop through from index 1
  for (var i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
    var currentWord = words[i];
    
    // Setting the longest word to the initial word here means that it will set the longest word to be "what" everytime your loop runs.
    
    if (longestWord.length < currentWord.length) {
      longestWord = currentWord;
    }
  }
  return longestWord;
}

console.log(longestWord("What the hell is going on"));
```

Comment: Start your loop with `i = 1`. There's no need to test element 0, since it's already in `longestWord`

Answer (score 1):

Jordan has given you the correct answer. We can also use sort function and return the first element as follows:

```js
function longestWord(string) {
    var words = string.split(' ');
    return words.sort(function (a, b) { return b.length - a.length; })[0];
}

console.log(longestWord("what the hell is going on"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I post the ES6 one-liner, just in case...

```js
let longestWord = str => str.split(' ').sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length)[0];

console.log(longestWord("what the hell is going on"));
```